# Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version.

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new to xamarin android and getting the error "Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version." and i tried changing compiled and target version but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Try set the Minimum Android version to Use Compile using SDK version and set the Target Android version to the same value as the Target Framework version. Or try to release your phone's memory( like uninstall some Apps).

Comment: i tried the same but problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3410/monodroid-does-not-support-running-the-previous-version) for example.

At least some years ago, MonoDroid (predecessor to Xamarin.Android) did not support running the previously built version. The error message looked quite similar

> MonoDroid does not support running the previous version. Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.

This may happen, when a build failed and you tried to debug it anyway. Visual Studio will offer to run the last successful build, which is not supported.

Check, if there are any build errors preventing the current version to be run.